# Unittesting DRF Serializer validators one by one

Tags: python, django, rest

We have an example Serializer class we'd like to test:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    fieldA = serializers.CharField()
    fieldB = serializers.CharField()
    def validate_fieldA(self,AVal):
        if len(AVal) < 3:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("AField must be at least 3 characters long")
        return AVal

    def validate_fieldB(self,BVal):
        if not len(BVal) < 3:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("BField must be at least 3 characters long")
        return BVal
```

This is a greatly simplified scenario, but it should do.

We want to write unittests for this Serializer class. My friend argues we should test using the .is_valid() method, like so

```
class TestMySerializer(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_validate_fieldA_long_enough(self):
        ser = MySerializer(data={"fieldA":"I'm long enough","fieldB":"Whatever"}),
        self.assertTrue(ser.is_valid())
        self.assertEqual(ser.validated_data["fieldA"],"I'm long enough")

    def test_validate_fieldA_too_short(self):
        ser = MySerializer(data={"fieldA":"x","fieldB":"Whatever"})
        self.assertFalse(ser.is_valid())
    
    #similarly tests for fieldB
    ...
```

I argue that unittests are supposed to be atomic and test only one "thing" at a time. By using the .is_valid() method we run *every* validator in the class instead of just the one we want to test. This introduces an unwanted dependency, where tests for fieldA validators may fail if there's something wrong with fieldB validators. So instead I would write my tests like so:

```
class TestMySerializer(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.ser = MySerializer()

    def test_fieldA_validator_long_enough(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.ser.validate_fieldA("I'm long enough"),"I'm long enough")

    def test_fieldA_validator_too_short(self):
        with self.assertRaises(serializers.ValidationError) as catcher:
            self.ser.validate_fieldA('x')
        self.assertEqual(str(catcher.exception),"AField must be at least 3 characters long")
    #same for fieldB validators
    ...
```

Which approach is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

You should not, in my opinion, specifically test the validation of your overly long chain.
It makes no sense because you are not the author of the code that performs this validation.
You must test your serializer and its various validation and invalidation cases.
The maximum length validator was written in Django Rest Framework and has already been tested.

The unit test that you write verifies the validation of specific input data.
So, in my opinion, you should call the method that is typically called for this purpose, which in your case is `is_valid()`.
You could also call `run_validators()`, but that would only test the Django Rest Framework's functionality, which is unnecessary in your case (I specify that there are relevant cases to test a lib included, but not here for me)